# CSS transition have an unwanted effect on the first letters of the text within a block, when hover over it

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I have a simple block with a text within and everything looks normal, but when I hover over a block, in the process the text acts weird: first letters of each word are moving down. I don't face the same problem when I remove transition from the code. I've searched through other questions connected with CSS transition problems, but couldn't find a solution to this problem. Could somebody explain me, please, why is this happening and how to avoid such behavior?

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/ad-ovo/pen/amRLwG)

Here is the [link](http://sendvid.com/ara1kd0e), where you can see how it behaves

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box grow">
    <p>Box grow</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.29, 0.01, 0.72, 1);
}

.grow:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15, 1.15);
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D, it was the first question, where I looked for the answer and it doesn't have a solution for fixing the problem with the first letter moving effect. As for blurry text, I've edited my question

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, you can add `backface-visibility: hidden;` to you `.box` div, and then set `translate3d(0, 0, 0);` on the hover.

**CSS**

```
.box {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.grow:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15, 1.15) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/jrZamz)**

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, but there is still a problem with the first letters. I've edited the question and provided the link to show where the problem is

Comment: @Olga, I don't see that happening in my CodePen. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I use Chrome and I've also checked in Opera, Firefox, IE

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue on my Mac in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

Comment: Then maybe it has something to do with Windows? Anyway, thank you!